# ¿Puedo usar objetos en una base de datos?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una caso que no sé cual es la mejor estructura de la base de datos relacional.

**Usuario**

- ID
- Nombre

**Tarea**

- ID
- Nombre

Quiero que se cumplan las siguientes condiciones

1. Un usuario puede asignar la tarea a otro usuario
2. Requiero que  haya un apartado donde te muestre todas las tareas que asignaste.

Mi solución era poner una tabla nueva llamada

**Responsable**

- ID
- Responsable (User.id)
- Quien_asigna (User.id)
- Tarea (Tarea.id)

Entonces con programación realizaría una validación:

```
if( User.id == Responsable.Quien_asigna ) 
 TareasCreadasPorUsuario.AgregarTarea()


Mostrar(TareasCreadasPorUsuario);
```

Pero, me preguntaba si no sería mejor, o si era posible mejor poner algo así.

**Tarea**

- ID
- Nombre
- Responsables[Responsable, Quien_asigna]

Y al final en programación

```
for(Responsable in Tarea.Responsables)
  if( User.id == Responsable.Quien_asigna ) 
     TareasCreadasPorUsuario.AgregarTarea()


Mostrar(TareasCreadasPorUsuario);
```

Comment: no alcanza con agregarle a la tabla tarea esos dos campos que vos queres? (responsable, asignada por)?

Comment: Creo que no, porque requiero múltiples responsables en algunas tareas. Lo que me llevaría a lo mismo, ¿puedo agregar un array al campo responsable y asignada por? Y posteriormente, ¿sería la posición del array lo que indica quien agregó a qué usuario determinado? 

Creo que tal vez es de prácticas, pero no tengo mucha experiencia maquetando todo.

Comment: no. Estas en una base de datos relacional. No hay arrays ni esas cosas. Hay tablas, y las tablas tienen datos. Si no sabes sobre relaciones entre tablas, deberias ver ese tema ahora. Lo que vas a tener es una tabla de relaciones entre tareas y responsables, donde tendras la tarea, el responsable y quien asigno ese responsable.

Comment: Es como dice @gbianchi. Si te cuesta verlo sin relacionarlo con objetos. Piensa como que tienes dos tablas "padres" denominadas tareas y  responsables. Todo aquello que no se pueda contemplar en ninguna de las dos pero que las relacione puede originar una tabla "hija" digamos que se llama "tareasxresponsables" donde tengas aquellos atributos (campos) que no pertenezcan directamente a esas tablas padres. Como todo hijo "tareasxresponsables" puede heredar (a través de las claves foráneas) los atributos de sus padres. Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!